# Get result from laravel relation

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel **VERSION = '5.6.22'** . I have two tables **t_project_employee** and **employees** table

In t_project_employee i am storing the project_id and assigned employees.

```
eg pe_emp_id   emp_id
   01          25
   01          36
   02          25
```

In employee table i am storing employee details.

I am trying to fetch all employees who is assigned for a particular project.

```
 public function employees(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Employee','emp_id','pe_emp_id')->select(array('emp_id', 'f_name','l_name'));
}
```

I am getting all projects and inside project  i am getting employees. i need only employees details assigned to the projects. i done using the above code. how can i do this

```
return TProjectEmployees::where("pe_prj_id",$projectId)->with("employees")->get();
```

I am using above code in controller

```
[
{
    "pe_id": 1,
    "pe_prj_id": 1,
    "pe_emp_id": 54,
    "pe_role_id": 1,
    "pe_startdate": "2018-07-11",
    "pe_enddate": "2018-07-19",
    "pe_IsActive": 1,
    "employees": {
        "emp_id": 54,
        "f_name": "Aglubat Micheal",
        "l_name": "Nicolas"
    }
},
```

is the result. I dont need the project details, I only need the employees

Answer (score 0):

As i show above example you have used hasOne relation as per my opinion use belongsTo relation because one project may be assign to multiple employee right? so your code will become like below:

```
public function employees() {

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee','emp_id','pe_emp_id')->select(array('emp_id', 'f_name','l_name'));
}
```

Comment: I am getting full data including project. I only need the employee details

Comment: try query   return TProjectEmployees::select('employees.*')->where("pe_prj_id",$projectId)->with("employees")->get();

Comment: I am getting error Unknown table 'mex.employees' (SQL: select `employees`.* from `t_project_employee` where `pe_prj_id` = 1)

Answer (score 0):

You have a faulty relationship here.  t_project_employees seems like an intermediate, or pivot, table for a many-to-many relationship.  Therefore, you wouldn't have a model for that table or ever query that table directly.  You'd have a [belongsToMany](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship on both the Projects and Employees Model.

Employee Model:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Project::class, 't_project_employees');
}
```

Then query that relation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations.

```
Employee::whereHas('projects', function($q) use ($projectId) {
    $q->where('id', $projectId);
});
```